# Ubiquiti Unifi for Raspberry Pi no longer working, how to download old version?

Tags: controller, updates, ubiquity

i updated my raspberry pi unifi installation with the following

sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' -y -q full-upgrade
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -oDpkg::Options::='--force-confold' -y -q --only-upgrade install $unifi-7.4

Woops.. service broken.

As suggested in other forums to address this issue: [Found left-over process (mongod) in control group while starting unit. Ignnoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLBL2.png)I switched my Raspbian to 64 bit

purged mongodb and unifi, reinstalled unifi 7.4 (lost config, who cares) and the service cannot start.  now service shows
[BUG] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred #188

I ignored this and the web interface has "404."

I'd like to just forget all these issues and roll back to the old version, I don't have time to troubleshoot it anymore.   what is the best way to get the old version of unifi controlller?

Tried
sudo apt-get install unifi=7.2

then I tried:
wget https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/5.6.42/unifi_sysvinit_all.deb && dpkg -i unifi_sysvinit_all.deb && rm unifi_sysvinit_all.deb

I was able to get version 5.6.42 but it failed to install because of mongo dependencies.  There's old documentation saying it can't have mongo DB 3.6 or higher.  now I'm back to my original question.  Then that has its own dependencies...............

etc.

hoping to get any working unifi controller.

Comment: ask this on the raspberry pi forums

Answer (score 0):

Same problems - reverted back to 7.3.83 on RPI4